# "malformed htpasswd file" error message when starting pypi-server

Tags: python, .htaccess, pypi, .htpasswd, passlib

When starting the [pypi-server](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver) I get an error message saying "**malformed htpasswd file**". I get the error message even if the .htpasswd file does not exist. What is causing the error?

Here is the entire Traceback:

```
C:\Data>pypi-server -p 8080 -P packages\.htaccess packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pypi-server.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pypiserver\__main__.py", line 293, in main
    app = pypiserver.app(**vars(c))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pypiserver\__init__.py", line 124, in app
    config, packages = core.configure(**kwds)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pypiserver\core.py", line 47, in configure
    htPsswdFile = HtpasswdFile(c.password_file)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\passlib\apache.py", line 583, in __init__
    super(HtpasswdFile, self).__init__(path, **kwds)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\passlib\apache.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\passlib\apache.py", line 236, in load
    self._load_lines(fh)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\passlib\apache.py", line 261, in _load_lines
    key, value = parse(line, idx+1)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\passlib\apache.py", line 590, in _parse_record
    % lineno)
ValueError: malformed htpasswd file (error reading line 1)
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
C:\Data\packages\.htaccess 
C:\Data\packages\.htpasswd
```

The content of the .htaccess file is:

```
AuthName "Under Development"
AuthUserFile C:\Data\packages\.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user
```

The content of the .htpasswd file is:

```
user:$apr1$zYBRb3n6$PBrNqfGoyb9ZQC5hGuRJN0
```

Comment: how are you starting pypi-server?

Comment: I start the pypi-server in the terminal by typing: "pypi-server -p 8080 -P packages\.htaccess packages". I added therefore "C:\Python27\Scripts" to the "Path" environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *pypiserver* does not support `.htaccess` files; this is an Apache-only feature. it just reuses the  `.htpasswd` file-format from Apache.

Additionally, the `htpasswd` file is better not to be located inside the `packages` folder, to be impossible for *pypiserver* to serve it by mistake, and reveal thus its contents.

So move the htpasswd file e.g. to the parent folder, remove the dot prefix (no need to be hidden/special), and change the startup command:

```
move packages\.htpasswd .\htpasswd
del packages\.htaccess
pypiserver -p 8080 -P htpasswd packages
```

Comment: You said that "the pypiserver does not support .htaccess files;" But why is it written on https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver to start the pypi-server with the .htaccess file: "./pypi-server -p 8080 -P .htaccess ~/packages &"?